# Ajax response not in correct order and nothing displayed in div while using for loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, for-loop

I am calling **ajax** in **for** loop. The `ajax response` is getting but not in correct order.

I have to display the first response in first div, second response in second div and so on.. But nothing is displayed. However I alert the data(response), it is correct but not in correct order.

My code is:

```
function loadanswer(){
    var nos = $("#nos").val();
    for(var h=0;h<nos;h++){

        var lang = $("#hdn_lan_"+h).val();
        var filename = $("#hdn_lanfile_"+h).val();
        var pv = $("#hdn_pv_"+h).val();
        $.post("ajaxCoderun.php", {filename:filename,lang:lang,pv:pv},function(data){
            alert(data);
            $("#ca_"+h).html("<span style='color:green;'>Correct Answer is: <b>"+data+"</b></span>");

        });
    }
    }

    loadanswer();
```

I heard that I can set time delay, how and where?

Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: You could number the responses in the order you want.  Then in javascript, cycle through the responses and put them in a sorted array.  Then display them after they are sorted.

Answer (score 1):

An ajax request is by default asyncronous. So that's why you get the response in different order.

You can either change the ajax to syncronous (not recommended) or you get the whole data in one request and loop through the response.

This would be the setting for a syncronious request:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: remote_url,
        data: postData,
        async: false,
        success : function(data) {
            remote = data;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `async:false`

like

```
$.ajax({
url:'yoururl',
type:'post',
data:{a:a,b:b},
async:false
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use recursion in your loop? This solution allows you to wait for response before launching a new request, so the final order should be the correct.

```
loadanswer();

function loadanswer(nos, h) {

        if (typeof nos === typeof undefined) {
            nos = $('#nos').val();
            h = 0;
        }

        var lang = $("#hdn_lan_"+h).val();
        var filename = $("#hdn_lanfile_"+h).val();
        var pv = $("#hdn_pv_"+h).val();
        $.post("ajaxCoderun.php", {filename:filename,lang:lang,pv:pv},function(data){
            alert(data);
            $("#ca_"+h).html("<span style='color:green;'>Correct Answer is: <b>"+data+"</b></span>");
            if (h < nos) {
                 loadanswer(nos, h++);
            }

        });
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got a solution:

I pass a new parameter, `h` to `ajax` page, where `h` is the `for` loop variable. In **ajaxCoderun.php** page I append the new variable along with the result. Its look like:

```
$num = $_POST['num'];

echo $result."^".$num;
```

And in jquery page I split the data and set the result in corresponding div.

Now my code is look like this:

```
function loadanswer(){
    var nos = $("#nos").val();
    var res = "";
    for(var h=0;h<nos;h++){

        var lang = $("#hdn_lan_"+h).val();
        var filename = $("#hdn_lanfile_"+h).val();
        var pv = $("#hdn_pv_"+h).val();
        //alert(lang+" & "+ filename +" & "+pv);
        $.post("ajaxCoderun.php", {filename:filename,lang:lang,pv:pv,num:h},function(data){
            //alert(data);
            var dataArray = data.split("^");
            $("#ca_"+dataArray[1]).html("<span style='color:green;'>Correct Answer is: <b>"+dataArray[0]+"</b></span>");

        });
    }
    }
    loadanswer();
```